# Collection count using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I am trying to display the total registered users in the admin panel.

Below is my code to get the total count

```js
exports.getcount = async (req, res) => {
  Client.count({}, function (err, count) {
    console.log("Number of users:", count);
    res.status(200).json({
      message: `Registered  Clients ${count}`,
    });
  });
};
```

In my client schema, I have an isDeleted field that is either true or false. In my total count, I just want to return those clients which contain `isDeleted:false`.

Comment: Instead of `.count()` you could use `.countDocuments({ isDeleted: false })` . Here are the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.countDocuments)

Comment: can you answer it with code so I can mark it.?

Comment: No problem, done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.count()`, which is deprecated (see [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-count) ), you could use `.countDocuments({ isDeleted: false })`.

`countDocuments` accepts a filter that will match documents in your database collection. Here are the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-countDocuments)